# How to install "specific" Visual Studio templates

Tags: visual-studio-templates

In our project, we have created some custom Visual Studio templates. Then, the setup will copy them into VS ItemTemplates/ProjectTemplates folders (..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE). In order to make our VS templates effected, we have to execute **devenv /installvstemplates** to rebuild the VS template cache but this way takes much time since it will refresh all existing VS templates.

Is there any other way to do without executing the command above or any arguments could be passed along to specify a template? (i.e template name ...)?

Thanks in advance.